# How to separate ":" in a time data

Tags: r

I have a time column in a database, where hours and minutes are separated by a ":". I would like to remove the ":" so that time field becomes numeric as I will use numeric time for some calculation.

Input:
X
00:00
01:15
02:30

Output:
X
0000
0115
0230

I am new to R. My apologies if this is a silly question. Greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> x <- c("00:00", "01:15", "02:30")
> gsub(":", "", x)
[1] "0000" "0115" "0230"
```

If you really want numbers you can coerce to `numeric` or `integer`

```
> as.numeric(gsub(":", "", x))
[1]   0 115 230
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much! I was not aware of gsub. Thanks again. It works.

Comment: In this case, `sub` would also work.  `sub` replaces the first occurrence in each string.  `gsub` replaces all occurences. Observe the difference between `sub(":", "", "10:10:10")` and `gsub(":", "", "10:10:10")`

Answer (score 2):

GSee's answer does what you ask. However, if you're doing arithmetic with units of time, you might think about some easier ways.

```
library(lubridate)
X <- hm(c("00:00", "01:15", "02:30")) # Converts to lubridate time objects

X + minutes(1)
# [1] "1M 0S"     "1H 16M 0S" "2H 31M 0S"

X + weeks(2)
# [1] "14d 0H 0M 0S"  "14d 1H 15M 0S" "14d 2H 30M 0S"
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be more sensible to use the R facilities for time parsing to convert first to date-time. At the moment you will have no way to capture the non-decimal character of your "time" values. 300-259  should be 1 , not 41. This set of commands illustrates some of R's date-time and Date functions:

```
> X <- c('00:00', '01:15', '02:30')
> as.POSIXct(X, format="%H:%M")
[1] "2013-08-05 00:00:00 PDT" "2013-08-05 01:15:00 PDT" "2013-08-05 02:30:00 PDT"
```

This will give the results in differences in seconds from midnight today:

```
> as.numeric(as.POSIXct(X, format="%H:%M") - as.POSIXct("2013-08-05 00:00:00 PDT"))
[1]    0 4500 9000
```

Now try to use todays's date, but then notice that there is an offset of 7 hours because as.POSIXct will assume this is GMT.UCT time:

```
> as.numeric(as.POSIXct(X, format="%H:%M") - as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()))
[1] 7.00 8.25 9.50
> as.numeric(as.POSIXct(X, format="%H:%M") - (as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())+7*3600))
[1]    0 4500 9000
```

So finish off the process by shifting 7 hours (=7*3600 seconds) and then converting to minutes:

```
> as.numeric(as.POSIXct(X, format="%H:%M") - (as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())+7*3600))/60
[1]   0  75 150
```